# React - Interacting with the state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple React counter which has a h2 that displays a count that starts at 0 and it has three buttons: Increment by one, reduce by one and reset the count.

In this app, the count is going to be the state, and since it is such a small example, it would make sense to make only one component, such as this:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");

class Counter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { count: 0 };
        this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this);
        this.reduceCount = this.reduceCount.bind(this);
        this.resetCount = this.resetCount.bind(this);
    }

    incrementCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    }

    reduceCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count - 1
        });
    }

    resetCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: 0
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Count count={this.state.count} />
                <button onClick={this.incrementCount}>+1</button>
                <button onClick={this.reduceCount}>-1</button>
                <button onClick={this.resetCount}>Reset</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />, body
);
```

And this works just fine.

However, one of the goals of React is to separte the UI into components, so i would like to make a separate component called Action for the buttons, and one called Count that contains the h2, as well as the state and those action buttons. The problem is that i cannot create the functions for the onClick events inside of the Action component because the state is going to be in the Counter component, and there is when the fun with the this keyword starts.

Nonetheless, i came out with a workaround for that, which is passing the eventHandlers as props, this way:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");

class Count extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <h2>Count: {this.props.count}</h2>
    }

}

class Action extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.increment}>+1</button>      
                <button onClick={this.props.reduce}>-1</button>      
                <button onClick={this.props.reset}>Réinitialiser</button>      
            </div>
        );
    }

}

class Counter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { count: 0 };
        this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this);
        this.reduceCount = this.reduceCount.bind(this);
        this.resetCount = this.resetCount.bind(this);
    }

    incrementCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    }

    reduceCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count - 1
        });
    }

    resetCount() {
        this.setState({
            count: 0
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Count count={this.state.count} />
                <Action 
                    increment={this.incrementCount}
                    reduce={this.reduceCount}
                    reset={this.resetCount}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />, body
);
```

This also works, but i have not seen this workaround mentioned when i have looked for this. Of course, i admitted do not know very well how to look for this doubt.

Is this a good practice? What other way could i do this?

Comment: I would personally remove the `Count` component, and put that in your first `Counter` component as well, and go with that. Splitting up components into subcomponents just for the sake of it doesn't feel like it gives you any benefits.

Comment: Passing event handlers happens *all the time* in React; I'm not sure how you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. Actually in the Reactjs site, the excellent examples found in the homepage does not split components like this. It is just that this is the only example i had that was simple enough to approach it in two different ways. And i think that i will encounter with this again soon on a larger app.

Comment: @DaveNewton I only have limited experience in React, like a week of learning it. Do you mean that it is a valid approach? My question is more if it feels more like a workaround than an actual solution.

Comment: @Tholle It's not "just for the sake of it"; breaking down components makes testing easier, allows easier discovery of re-use, etc. Here the `Count` component is responsible for a single thing: displaying the count. Not unreasonable at all, although it's a useless ctor and should be a stateless component. Moving the buttons into its own component also makes sense. OP states they're experimenting with a simple case--but even in simple cases it's often still easier to break things up.

Comment: @ManuAlvarado22 A "workaround" for what? This is how React works. If parent components have state that children need to manipulate you either pass click handlers (like basically every React component ever does) or you use a different state management solution like Redux. If you have deeply-nested components that need to modify state at a high level then something like Redux makes more sense, otherwise you have tons of redundant property passing, although there are mechanisms to assist with this as well.

Comment: For changing the state.
Excellent, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smarter and easiest way you make components that are readable and easy to maintain then they are good enough.

If I refactor your components then I will do this way:  [checkThisPen](https://codesandbox.io/embed/llw8m81j07)

**When I create a function?**

1. For readability of the code, I move a bunch of code to a specific
   function.
2. If I am reusing a peace of the code for some logic across the file; Then I make that logic into a function and reuse it.
3. I export the function if it is used across multiple components or files in the project.

**When I create a Component?**

- Similar to the functions we create a component when it is used in multiple places or for repetitive processes.
- In your case I will create a ActionButton instead of the Action. Which is doing a similar functionality of Button with different props.

**NOTE:** Treat the ActionButton as the PureComponent or Fragment. Check the docs about PureComponent and Fragment for more info. Also use ES6 arrow functions for `incrementCount()`, `reduceCount()`, `resetCount()`. So that you don't need to bother about binding a function while rendering.